# Having a monthly photo competition in Meta?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I just came to know about this [Photo competition December 2018](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4861/photo-competition-december-2018) on Travel.SE.

I find it pretty much fun :-)
[I sort of informally asked if it okay to have such a thing at our meta site](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47891802#47891802).

But, that not everyone visit our chat: [The Base Camp](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2291/the-base-camp), I just wanted to ask what people think about it.

Your thoughts?

Comment: The photo competition for december can be found here: https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1343/3143

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No reason we can't run our own "competitions." There won't be a prize, of course, unless someone volunteers to provide one or badgers SE into providing something, but we can certainly have a post of people showing off their photos.

Comment: Wanted to make sure you saw this https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1613/i-think-its-time-to-pack-up-and-leave