# Photo Competition: December 2018 - Trails

Tags: feature-request, photo-competition

We are announcing a fun activity to have a photo competition each month.

There two sets of rules:

- Rules that are always applicable.
- Rules that are applicable to a particular theme of competition (Will typically be referred as 'Rules for :MonthName:')

---

Rules that are always applicable are as follows:

1. One photo per answer, and no more than 5 answers per user per month.
2. Post only photos taken by yourself.
3. All entries should include a line of text with the location and subject of the photo and the date the photo was taken
4. Refrain from posting sensitive/debatable content
5. There isn't a prize money/item/award as such. Respect and appreciation is what you earn here.

---

Rules for December are as follows:

1. It has to be a picture of a trail or a hiking path
2. The photo should not include people as important part of the picture. If unavoidable, people can be included as long as they are not recognisable.
3. No entries/photos should be posted before midnight, 1st of December 2018, voting will be applicable till midnight 31st of December and to be clear, we use UTC, just like the site itself.
4. There is no constraint on when the photo must have been taken.

Good luck!

---

Congratulations to [Shan-X!](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1352/4079) Our winner with 10 votes at end of the competition.

Comment: I think Sue's request is totally valid and would like her being able to also post the pictures of her husband.

Comment: okay @WedaPashi, admit it. You just started this to show off your gorgeous photos! :D

Comment: @Paul: Hahaha, okay, I admit it if that works :D Anyways, it is a lot of fun. Where have you been?

Comment: It is a lot of fun, and a great idea! I've been here and there, from time to time visiting as reader here, but was focused too much on other things to participate here a lot. I hope this will be a little different in the next time, but can't promise anything ;)

Comment: This is a good idea! :)

Comment: @liam: Welcome back! Good to see you :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Continental Divide Trail, somewhere in the middle of New-Mexico.

[image: CDT]

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Now? Look at the Photo Competition for January! :-)

Answer (score 9):

[image: This picture was taken on the Kungsleden (Sweden) in 2014, south of Tjäktja pass.]

This picture was taken on the Kungsleden (Sweden) in 2014, south of Tjäktja pass.

Comment: wow, that's beautiful! Which time of the year is it?

Comment: That was mid august. It was still raining several times a day, but otherwise nice weather. According to locals, it should have started snowing a month later, so july/august should be the ideal time if you want to visit. Just don't go when Fjäll Raven Classics floods the area with tourists.

Answer (score 7):

At 6000 feet on Mt Teide, Tenerife - looking towards the peak. 28 Oct 2018

[image: Mt Teide and rocky outcrops]

Answer (score 7):

This picture was taken in August of 2016, looking back up the trail towards Gannet Peak, the highest point in Wyoming and the most remote of all of the state highpoints. This was day 6 of the hike, I had summited the peak the day before.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The majestic Parvati valley, Greater Himalayas, India. August 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

The ghostly forests of the Goecha la trail, Sikkim, India. The [rhododendrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhododendron) provide a colorful feel to an otherwise scary forest. Circa May 2017.

[image]

Comment: "Scary" or "magical"? This is an amazing photo.

Answer (score 6):

Little trail on the north side of the Pentland Hills not far from my home, leading up towards a hiking trail and an old estate.

Photo by me 8 Dec 2018.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Pic taken atop a hill named [Kemmangundi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kemmangundi) in the western ghats, India. June 2017
[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is clicked on the way to [Kunzum La](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kunzum_Pass).
Altitude: 4,590 m or 15,060 ft.
Date: July 1st week, 2017.
The peaks in the background are (L to R): CB16, CB13A, CB13, CB14.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This was clicked on the way to Chandra Taal. Altitude: Appox 4200 m or 13,800 ft. The river in the picture is Chandra. This later has a confluence with *Bhaga* river near Keylong, and then it flows into Pakistan and more popularly called as [*Chenab*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chenab_River) river.

The cloud I fell in love with.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

[image: Valle de Viñales]

Uniting what the Valle de Viñales in Pinar del Río, Cuba, is famous for: Red earth, (here still fallow) tobacco fields, horses and the strange rock formations called mogotes.

Picture taken in July 2018.

Answer (score 5):

Taken on a winter walk, back in 2012, in the [National park Zuid Kennemerland.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zuid-Kennemerland_National_Park)
This is a typical trail in the park, which covers dunes. The highest hill of the area, as far as I know, is all of 45 meters.

[image: short part uphill between winter trees]
Photo by me, Willeke, can be used by all.

Answer (score 5):

This was clicked on the way to [Chandra Taal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandra_Taal).
Altitude: Appox 4200 m or 13,800 ft.
The river in the picture is *Chandra*, after confluence with *Bhaga*, it flows into Pakistan and more popularly called as [*Chenab*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chenab_River) river.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Pico San Juan]

View from Pico San Juan, highest elevation (1156 m) in the Sierra del Escambray in Cuba. Picture taken March 2018.

Comment: Gorgeous, but what is the black dot in the sky?  It looks like a skier taking a BIG jump.

Comment: @ab2 It's a bird. A vulture; probably one of the in Cuba omnipresent turkey vultures. But I can see what you mean, although I would interpret it as a snowboarder. :D

Answer (score 5):

[image: Valle the Viñales]

Tropical thunderstorm building up above on of the mogotes in Valle de Viñales in Pinar del Río, Cuba. Better not take that trail straight into it if you don't want to get wet!

Picture taken in July 2018.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
The desolate desert like terrain of the Spiti Valley, Himachal Pradesh India. Far off one can see the village of Mudh. One of the last villages in this valley. Pic taken circa August 2017

Answer (score 4):

Trail to La Grande Soufrière (active volcano) on Guadeloupe.

[image: trail to volcano]

Answer (score 2):

Bit late I know but here's a photo from this summer. I'm the one in red contemplating my next climb of the evening. This was a meet of the [Clwyd Climbing Club](http://clwyd.clubmesh.com) at a [crag called Pandy](https://www.ukclimbing.com/logbook/crag.php?id=428)

[image]