# Can we get a featured image added to the site theme?

Tags: discussion, design

### This has been running really well for 7 months I say we ask for it.

In the [meta post on the new themes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/319274/responsive-design-themes-what-can-sites-customize-and-how-can-they-get-changes?cb=1) it says,

> But, what this means is that if *one* site has an element, other sites can pretty easily add it.
>
> For example, the Photography site's Photo of the Week box could be added to Graphic Design to show off the users' designs if that site wanted to host such a weekly contest.

[image: The top of the Photography site, showing the Photo of the Week element.]

People seem to be enjoying the photography contest, would the photo of the week be something we would like to request here?

Update, I asked on the meta post, we will have to see how it goes.

Comment: Do we know if this feature is available to beta sites, or only graduated sites?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I don't know, I am pretty sure all the sites have the same base theme so it should be possible from a technical perspective

Comment: Have you made the request yet?

Comment: @JamesJenkins The main meta post says "One other thing, when you start these discussions on your child meta sites, be sure to use the design tag so that we can find and track them easily." so I added the tag. Not sure of where we are supposed to go put in a request

Comment: From what I am [seeing here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/319274/217279) it looks like you either start a [new meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) or ping catija to get things started. Do you wan to take the lead on getting catija involved?

Comment: @JamesJenkins I added a comment to the meta post, will see where it goes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, provided that we have a couple of months of success with [the monthly photo contest](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1341/having-a-monthly-photo-competition-in-meta)

Top photo from last month is next month's featured image.